# Message:trying to get property 'total' of non-object in

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql

[image]

[image]

I got this project from another dev, I didn't put my server with PHP Version 7.2.34-36+ubuntu20.04.1+deb.sury.org+1.
when I click the button it won't do "header('Location: /');"

just exit the login page when I do f5

This is accountController

```
   public function login()
    {
        if(Authentication::logged())
        {
            header('Location: /');
            exit();
        }
        $this->title = 'Login';

        $this->tokenId = Forms::getTokenID();
        $this->tokenValue = Forms::getToken();
        $this->inputs = Forms::formNames(['email', 'password', 'mode'], false);

        if($this->getParams(0) == 'action')
        {
            sleep(2);

            $try = AuthenticationFactory::login($this->inputs);

            echo $try;

            $json = Json::decode($try);

            if($json->success)
            {
                $this->inputs = Forms::formNames(['email', 'password', 'mode'], true);
            }

            die();
        }

        $this->view();
    }
```

I tried to put the update time after logging in, found it to be a .htaccess problem. tried with other php versions, and some code changes. I don't know where I'm wrong

Comment: you should wrap one more round bracket around the select query. open before "$this" and end before "->total". try this out.

Comment: I think that the problem is that you don't have that table in your database.

Comment: `$this->select(…)->total` is the line in question. The error is telling you that te result of that `select` function is not an object. Presumably, the query failed and the method has some logic that hides the underlying cause from you.

Comment: thanks for the help had a problem, table in the field "block CLIENT_ID" was wrong that field